# Appengine Modules: dispatch.yaml inactive on dev server

Tags: google-app-engine

I'm trying yo test the new "modules" feature but unfortunately they don't seem to load in my dev environment (osx + python).

I followed this doc https://developers.google.com/appengine/docs/python/modules/routing#Python_Routing_in_the_development_server

Since i couldn't get my modules to load, I found this test app: https://github.com/GoogleCloudPlatform/appengine-modules-helloworld-python  but unfortunately I'm experiencing the same problem.

The dispatch.yaml files uses relative routes.

Here are the logs:

- INFO     2013-08-30 00:14:20,702 sdk_update_checker.py:245] Checking for updates to the SDK.
- INFO     2013-08-30 00:14:21,067 sdk_update_checker.py:273] The SDK is up to date.
- INFO     2013-08-30 00:14:21,252 api_server.py:138] Starting API server at: localhost:58478
- INFO     2013-08-30 00:14:21,255 dispatcher.py:164] Starting module "default" running at: localhost:8080
- INFO     2013-08-30 00:14:21,259 admin_server.py:117] Starting admin server at: localhost:8000
- INFO     2013-08-30 00:14:58,871 module.py:593] default: "GET / HTTP/1.1" 200 36
- INFO     2013-08-30 00:15:12,914 module.py:593] default: "GET /mobile/ HTTP/1.1" 404 154

if / works, I get a 404 for /mobile and /work.
Based on the doc we should also see the 2 modules mobile-frontend and static-backend started.

Let me know if you have an idea.

Thanks,

Oliv

Comment: Hi Oliv.. Did you solve this issue.. if yes, kindly share how.. i am using GAE Python on Windows 7.. Development SDK 1.9.2..

Answer (score 10):

Have you specified the dispatch.yaml when you start the SDK?

dev_appserver.py dispatch.yaml app.yaml my_module_a.yaml my_module_b.yaml

You will see them start an instance on different ports, just like a backend. You should see in the console,

```
Starting dispatcher running at: http://localhost:8080
```

(or whatever port you specified)

This can be found at the bottom of this page, although isn't obvious how you get dev_appserver to run with a dispatch.yaml

**UPDATE** As Zachary points out in the comments you don't need to mention dispatch.yaml any longer. Just specifying separate .yaml files for each module is enough. Make sure that if the paths to each yaml is correct in relation to the directory you are running dev_appserver.py in.

Update docs are [here](https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/python/modules/#devserver)

Comment: Thank you for this answer Justin, unfortunately GAE documentation has changed and I cannot find any mention of specifying `dispatch.yaml` as an additional paremter to `dev_appserver.py`.  There's a very clear instruction and how to run multiple modules, sans dispatch, here: https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/python/modules/#devserver

Comment: Thanks Zachary. Only just seen your comment. I've updated the answer.

Comment: Specifying multiple .yaml files on dev_appserver.py renders all routes 404 now.