# Cron.yaml doesn't route requests to proper module on dev server

Tags: python, google-app-engine, cron

I'm using GAE 1.9.2 -- I have a cron.yaml file with a specific request I want routed to a module called updater.yaml. In my cron.yaml file I have:

```
cron:
- description: Daily updater
  url: /update
  schedule: every day 02:00
  timezone: America/New_York
  target: updater
```

I loaded my two modules to my dev server with:

```
$ dev_appserver.py app.yaml updater.yaml
```

Any ideas? Thanks.

**Edit**:

Relevant part of updater.yaml:

```
application: [my app name]
module: updater
version: one
runtime: python27
api_version: 1
threadsafe: true
instance_class: B4_1G
basic_scaling:
  max_instances: 1

handlers:
- url: /update
  script: downloader.application
  login: admin
```

**Edit 2**:

I get this error on my app when hosted on google (i.e. not running on my dev_server) so it seems a handler isn't getting setup correctly...?:

```
W 2014-04-08 02:00:02.687 No handlers matched this URL.
```

Comment: Do you get error or what?

Comment: I get a 404 error when I click "run now" in the dev console.. I'm guessing it's because app.yaml doesn't have an /update url handler, but updater.yaml does..

Comment: do you have two modules displayed in localhost:8000? https://developers.google.com/appengine/docs/python/modules/routing

Comment: Yes -- do I need to do something with dispatch.yaml? I added the relevant part of updater.yaml to my previous post.

Comment: Yup I think you need to specify the dispatcher. Look at this post for more information http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18523234/appengine-modules-dispatch-yaml-inactive-on-dev-server

Answer (score 0):

From your error message, it looks like the updater module doesn't have the handler mapped correctly.  Make sure you can call the /update url manually in the browser and that you get the correct log output.

I use cron.yaml with a target module in production right now.  There is no dispatch.yaml entry for that module.